# Potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, httpwebrequest, system.web

I am running an ASP.Net MVC application and facing the following error. As I am new to ASP.Net, could someone please help me as to what does it mean and how can I resolve it?

I tried googling to understand it, but found different answers for the same error which left me more confused.

> Exception caught in Global.asax:System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$MainContent$WarningCtl1$TXTWarningText="
>
> This is the warni...").
>          at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
>          at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateNameValueCollection(NameValueCollection nvc, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
>          at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()
>          at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm()
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull)
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode()
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>          at ASP.app_config_appttypes_groupappttypes_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>          at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>          at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Please suggest.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to accept HTML markup as part of your request. You have a WYSIWYG editor on the page or something?

Comment: Have you tried adding the attribute `[ValidateInput(false)]` to your controller class?

Comment: I am putting it in my web.config file as <pages theme="Admin" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="AutoID" validateRequest="false"/>

Answer (score 8):

You need to add the `ValidateInputAttribute` to your controller (which applies it to all of your action methods for that controller, so be careful):

```
[ValidateInput (false)]
public class MyController : Controller { ... }
```

Or your action method:

```
public class MyOtherController : Controller
{
    [ValidateInput (false)]
    public ActionResult MyActionMethod (MyObjectThatTakesInHtml myObject)
    { ... }
}
```

**Edit**

As @dotjoe pointed out, and I forgot to mention, you also have access to the `AllowHtmlAttribute` (found in `System.Web.Mvc`) on a property in your model.

```
public class MyObjectThatTakesInHtml
{
    [AllowHtml]
    public string MyHtmlProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I am putting this in my web.config 
<pages theme="Admin" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="AutoID" validateRequest="false"/>

Comment: don't forget about the `AllowHtml` attribute ;)

Comment: But still I am facing the issue after that... Does [ValidateInput(false)] work different than validateRequest="False" in web.config?

Comment: @dotjoe doh, forgot about that one.  =D  Thanks.

Comment: np, I think you can only use AllowHtml at the property level...so it'd be on the property inside the `MyObjectThatTakesInHtml`

Comment: hey by the way value for allowhtml should be true right... I am using vb.net and hence cannot use [allowhtml] tag... instead I would have to use this <AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple := False,  _
 Inherited := True)> _

Comment: How do you add it in vb.net? I am getting error for [allowhtml]

Comment: @dotjoe I'm on fire with this one, tried to toss that out in a hurry.  Thanks for all the help and being a second set of eyes.

Comment: @tech_learning you just need to use VB.NET formatting instead of C# to decorate your code with attributes.

Answer (score 4):

- **Encode at client level and decode it in Server Level**

Steps

1.Post the form using jquery submit method.

in jquery button click event method encode field that you want to post to server. example

```
$("#field").val(encodeURIComponent($("#field").val())) $("#formid").submit();
```

In Controller Level access all form id value using

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request["fieldid"])
```

Make sure controller method dont have parameter.

Answer (score -1):

MVC

Added attribute to action
[ValidateInput(false)]

and confirm web.config setting in system.web